# Android Jetpack Compose and Login screen

Tags: android, firebase, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm facing an issue and I can't understand what is happening here.

I'm using FirebaseUI for authentication and I have this logic on my composable:

```
if (isAnonymousUser && authResultCode != AuthResultCode.CANCELLED) {
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        loginLauncher.launch(viewModel.buildLoginIntent()) //This trigger the UI Sign in flow
    }
}
if (!isAnonymousUser) {
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        navController.popBackStack()
        navController.navigate(Screen.HomeScreen.route)
    }
}
```

The problem are these lines

```
if (!isAnonymousUser) {
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        navController.popBackStack()
        navController.navigate(Screen.HomeScreen.route)
    }
}
```

If I remove the `LaunchedEffect`, I can move to `HomeScreen` but the `navController.navigate` is called in a loop and the application becomes unusable. This comes from the view model:

```
val isAnonymousUser = viewModel.isAnonymousUser.collectAsState().value
```

Instead using `LaunchedEffect` it doesn't happen. What is happening? Help me to understand, I think the problem is on the `MutableState` of `isAnonymousUser`

Comment: Composition should be [side-effect free](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) as they can be called many, many times (as in, for each frame of the crossfade animation between destinations). What makes you think you should remove the `LaunchedEffect`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake The documentation talks about suspend fun, I didn't know that navigation could make this happen

Comment: What about using @NonRestartableComposable instead of LaunchedEffect? What is best practice in this use case?